# If $x_n\in l^1(\mathbb{K})$ and $x_n\rightarrow 0$ in $X_p$, then $x_n\rightarrow 0$ in $X_1$?

Tags: banach-spaces

Is it true that if $x_n\in l^1(\mathbb{K})$ and $x_n\rightarrow 0$ in $X_p$, then $x_n\rightarrow 0$ in $X_1$?

Where $X_1= (l^1(\mathbb{K}),\|.\|_1)$ and
$X_p=(l^1(\mathbb{K}),\|.\|_p)$

I know that $l^1(\mathbb{K})$ is subspace of $l^p(\mathbb{K})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume $p\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \geq 2$)

It is not true. Let $x_n \in \ell^1$ be the sequence
$$
x_{n,k} :=
\begin{cases}
n^{-\frac{2}{p}} & , ~k \leq n \\
0 &, ~k > n
\end{cases}.
$$
Then
$$
\lVert x_n \rVert_p^p = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \lvert x_{n, k} \rvert^p = \frac{1}{n} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}0.
$$
But:
$$
\lVert x_n \rVert_1 = n^{1 - \frac{2}{p}} \geq 1
$$